# Not able to see com tab under add reference window to add system.configuration dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, xunit, appsettings

I just created one xunit test project for .Net Core in VS2017. I added one appsettings.json file to the project. To access the config values from settings file, I'm trying to add system.configuration dll from com component to the project depedencies but I do not see Com Tab at all when I right click on Dependencies and select Add reference. All I see is Projects, Shared Projects and Browse to expand and select from. How to add system.configuration dll?

Appreciate any help.